# Magento2 API Filtering Multiple categories

Tags: magento2, php, api, soap, soap-api-v1

In Magento2 API, how would I filter by multiple categories?

> V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%test%&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=like&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][value]=105,106,107&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[pageSize]=8&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1

When the category ids are **105,106,107** I am getting results, but if the category ids are **107,106,105** I am getting empty items.

How can I search for different categories in Magento2 API?

Answer (score 0):

```
baseurl/rest/default/V1/products/products
searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0] 
[field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]= 
[8,4,2]&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=in

For multiple values need to use in please refer below devdocs 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html

**Note**: In your search criteria it ill take first category id only.
```

Comment: If it takes only first category then it will be a problem. If first category not having any products then we will get the empty results . same happening in my case as well. Any solution for this?

Comment: If you use eq it will happen like that yous should use in while you are using multiple categories

Answer (score 0):

Example with Guzzle:

```
        $response = $this->client->get('/rest/V1/products', [
        'search_criteria' => [
            'current_page' => $currentPage,
            'page_size' => $pageSize,
            'filter_groups' => [
                [
                    'filters' => [
                        [
                            'field' => 'category_id',
                            'value' => '23356,23355',
                            'condition_type' => 'in'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```